# Return percentage of LINESTRING (SQL Server 2008 Geography)

Tags: sql-server-2008, gis, sqlgeography

I want to create a function in SQL 2008 R2 that, given 3 parameters (`@path geography, @start_pct float, @end_pct float`), will return a linestring based on percentage of length of `@path`.

For example
when `@start_pct = 0` and `@end_pct = 0.5`, it will return the first half of `@path`, when `@start_pct = 0.5` and `@end_pct = 1`, it will return the last half of `@path`, when `@start_pct = 0.25` and `@end_pct = 0.75`, it will return middle 50% of `@path`, but - `@start_pct` and `@end_pct` could be anything (between 0 and 1)

I have tried:  I looped through each set of points using `STPointN` and calculated whether my points of interest lied within that section.  In my head it, the logic seemed sound, but it's not returning the expected results (of which I know the result)

I have the following sticking points:

1. Calculating a point which lies between 2 points on `@path`
2. I was storing my resulting linestring as a string (nvarchar(max)) but I
   think it may run out of space (some of the paths I am using have a
   lot of points).  I wanted to use `STLineFromText` at the end to
   convert it back to a geography.

Before I post my embarrassingly amateur code, I have a feeling that this should be somewhat easy and perhaps I'm over complicating it.

Has anyone done this before and could they lend a hand?

**Edit:**  Actually - just solved it, but still seems far more complicated than it should be.  Will post code when back in office.

Comment: Be sure and add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. You'll have to wait at least 24 hours before you can mark it as accepted.